# What are the potential problems with a rolling regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, moving-window

I have two time series that co-move, say a currency and a commodity, and the currency is highly impacted by the commodity, but also other factors. I'd like to determine when the currency becomes too expensive vis-a-vis the commodity, because I assume that there is some mean-reversion that will force the two to converge (in this case, currency remaining flat while commodity moves up, or currency moves down).
I'm employing a rolling regression with a large enough window, and estimate t+1 for all t, using the last |window| data points up to t. Then I plot the residuals between the estimate and the currency and it seems that when scaling the residuals, this approach catches turns in mean reversion very nicely.

What are the pitfalls in this approach? What could go wrong? Is this complete and utter nonsense?